# android application showing thread errors

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop a very basic application for the sake of playing with the android framework for now. I created a simple application with 3 activities. One that inserts data to database, one that handles the confirmation message and finally one that shows data entered so far.

I receive this error from the listing activity (the last executed) [image: Check picture to see error]

I am not very clear as to why this is happening but that is the logcat output. All I am trying to do is the following in that activity:

```
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (resEntity != null) {

                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);
                  TextView responseSimpleText = new TextView(this);
                  responseSimpleText.setText(responseStr.toString());
                // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response

                setContentView(responseSimpleText);
            }else{
                Log.v("ListingAcitivty.java", "Response is Null");
            }
```

Can someone please point out what is happening? I am using AsyncTask and data is inserted successfully using it.

Comment: I suppose this is part of `doInBackground` method of `AsynTask`. Please note this method doesn't allow you to update the view (you are calling `setContentView(responseSimpleText);` inside this method). Its because it is executed on the background thread and not UI thread.

Comment: I never knew this! thanks. best thing to do in this case would be?

Comment: Update your view in either `onPreExecute()`,`onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` or `onPostExecute(Result)`. More details you will find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception, it looks like you're trying to change something on the UI from a different thread than the UI one. You cannot do that directly.

> Because tasks that you run on a thread from a thread pool aren't running on your UI thread, they don't have access to UI objects.

From: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

That page also explains how this scenario should be approached.